# How to disable the hours before the start date&time using v-calendar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetime, vcalendar

I am using **v-calendar** to have the start date&time and end date&time using mode as `dateTime`. My requirement is to make the end date&time not go before the start date&time. For this, I am using `:min-date` prop bounded with start date&time value as shown in the below code.

```
<v-date-picker :min-date="this.formData.startDate" v-model="formData['endDate']" mode="dateTime" :timezone="timezone" name="End Date" class="dateTimePicker">
    <template v-slot="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
        <input
           class="px-2 py-1 border rounded focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300"
           :value="inputValue"
           v-on="inputEvents"
        />
    </template>
</v-date-picker>
```

Now let's say the start date&time selected is **Feb 10th, 05:00 AM** and while selecting the end date&time, the dates before the **10th** will be disabled. But If I select **10th** as the date(same date), I could still select **04:00 AM** as the time, which is not proper.

So is there a way of disabling the time with respect to the selected date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in their [documentation](https://vcalendar.io/api/v2.0/datepicker.html) you can pass `validHours` prop that is a function that returns if an hour is valid.

So depending on your implementaton you can do something like this:

```html
<v-date-picker :validHours="isHourValid()" :min-date="this.formData.startDate" v-model="formData['endDate']" mode="dateTime" :timezone="timezone" name="End Date" class="dateTimePicker" >
    <template v-slot="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
        <input
           class="px-2 py-1 border rounded focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300"
           :value="inputValue"
           v-on="inputEvents"
        />
    </template>
</v-date-picker>

<script>
  function isHourValid(hourThatIsSelected){
    let startDateVal = 12 // extract hour from formData['startDate'], eg. 12
    return hourThatIsSelected > startDateVal 
  }
</script>
```